# ASP.Net Web Api 2.2 generated help files not displaying api documentation

Tags: asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api

I have followed the steps to generate api help here http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages and this has been working fine.

Today, I've noticed that the Help page is not displaying anything in the api groups section.

This line;

```
ILookup<HttpControllerDescriptor, ApiDescription> apiGroups = Model.ToLookup(api => api.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor);
```

is not finding any groups to iterate through and display the api help for.

```
@using System.Web.Http
@using System.Web.Http.Controllers
@using System.Web.Http.Description
@using System.Collections.ObjectModel
@using MyCompany.WebApi.Areas.HelpPage.Models
@model Collection<ApiDescription>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Web API Help Page";

    // Group APIs by controller
    ILookup<HttpControllerDescriptor, ApiDescription> apiGroups = Model.ToLookup(api => api.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor);
}

<link type="text/css" href="~/Areas/HelpPage/HelpPage.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header class="help-page">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="float-left">
            <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div id="body" class="help-page">
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <h2>Introduction</h2>
            <p>
                Provide a general description of your APIs here.
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
        @foreach (var group in apiGroups)
        {
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => group, "ApiGroup")
        }
    </section>
</div>
```

I'm using Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage version 5.2.3, and same issue with 5.2.2.  Visual Studio 2015, MVC 5.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok it was a conflict between some code in StartUp.cs and Global.asax.cs

Normally in Global.asax you have this line;

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

but I had commented this out because of a bunch of changes I had done to use OWIN and get CORS configured.  So my StartUp.cs looked like this;

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);

            //Load any config settings from web.config
            MyConfiguration.Load();

            //Create AutoMapper maps.
            AutoMapperConfigurator.Configure();

            //write web api into Owin server pipeline.
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            //Get CORS working.
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }
```

and I thought as I'm calling WebApiConfig.Register in here I didn't need to call it in Global.asax.

Clearly, to get the api help working and generated I do still need to call GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register) in the Application_Start method.

Hope that helps.

Comment: To confirm, I had to remove the WebApiConfig.Register call from here.